# Limit a phpmyadmin user login to certain records

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have one database with a few phpmyadmin users created how do I limit each user to see just data meant for that specific user.

So user 1 will only see records with area code 082, user 2 will only see records with area code 083 and so on.

Is that possible and how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558081/mysql-limit-access-to-subset-of-records-for-each-user

Comment: Cross-posting is [not allowed on the Stack Exchange network](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, phpMyadmin does not allow customize of what users can see. To hide specific databases to certain users you need to enable [Configurable menus and user groups](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/privileges.html#configurable-menus-and-user-groups).

> By enabling $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] and
>   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] you can customize what users will
>   see in the phpMyAdmin navigation.

***However, it should be noted:***

> This feature only limits what a user sees, he is still able to use all
>   the functions. So this can not be considered as a security limitation.
>   Should you want to limit what users can do, use MySQL privileges to
>   achieve that.

Comment: I understand,it is not so much that I want to limit functions but rather only limit a user  to see data that conforms to a criteria and not see any of the other data in the same database. Thank you for your help.